# Java , i keep getting StringIndexOutOfboundsException

Tags: java, exception

This is supposed to isolate names and scores and then calculate the average of the scores. The output should look like this:

```
Student Name             Test 1    Test 2    Test 3     Final   Average 

Susan Smith                 76        78        90       100     88.80

Susan Boyd                 100        88        79        88     88.60

Alex Chandler               88        99        77        66     79.20
```

but it keeps throwing stringindexoutofboundsexception. Why?

This is the error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at CalcWeightedAverage.extractName(CalcWeightedAverage.java:49)
at CalcWeightedAverage.main(CalcWeightedAverage.java:30)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*; //import java.util for the scanner
import java.io.*;// import java io for printwriter

/**
 * class takes input file with scores and outputs scores with weighted average
 *
 * @author
 * @version 10/30/2015
 */
public class CalcWeightedAverage {
    /**
     * method akes input file with scores and outputs scores with weighted average
     *
     * @param String args
     * @return void
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // creating scanner to read from the keyboard
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the input file: "); // prompt for file name
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("OutputFile.txt"); // declares new printwriter for outputfile name
        String filename = in.nextLine(); // puts user input as filename
        File inFile = new File(filename);//makes a new file and puts user input in it 
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(inFile);// declaring scanner for whats in file
        out.printf("%-21s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s", "StudentName", "Test 1", "Test2", "Test 3", "Final", "Average"); // first line in output
        out.println(); // go to next line
        while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in1.nextLine(); // new string from file
            String studentName = extractName(line); // extracts the student name using the method
            double[] studentscore = new double[5]; // new array to store values
            studentscore = extractValue(line);// invoke method to calculate values
            out.printf("%-20s%10.0f%10.0f%10.0f%10.0f%10.2f", studentName, studentscore[0], studentscore[1], studentscore[2], studentscore[3], studentscore[4]); // edit scores
            out.println();// next line
        }
        in.close(); // closes scanner
        in1.close();//closes scanner
        out.close();//closes printwriter
    }


    /**
     * Extracts the student name from an input line.
     *
     * @param pline a line containing a student name, followed by a number
     * @return the student name
     */
    public static String extractName(String pline) {
        int i = 0; // Locate the start of the first digit
        while (!(Character.isDigit(pline.charAt(i)))) {
            i++;
        }
        return pline.substring(0, i).trim(); // Extract the student name and return
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the value from an input line.
     *
     * @param pline a line containing a student name, followed by a value
     * @return the value associated with the name
     */
    public static double[] extractValue(String pline) {
        int i = 0; // Locate the start of the first digit
        while (!Character.isDigit(pline.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        // Extract and convert the value
        String scoreString = pline.substring(i).trim(); // extract score and return
        Scanner score = new Scanner(scoreString); // new scanner for score
        int testScore1 = score.nextInt(); // value of first score
        int testScore2 = score.nextInt();// value of second score
        int testScore3 = score.nextInt();// value of third score
        int finalscore = score.nextInt();// value of final score
        double average = testScore1 * 0.2 + testScore2 * 0.2 + testScore3 * 0.2 + finalscore * 0.4; // calculates the weighted average
        double[] result = new double[5];// new array for input
        result[0] = testScore1;// value of first score
        result[1] = testScore2;// value of second score
        result[2] = testScore3;// value of third score
        result[3] = finalscore;//value of final score
        result[4] = average; // value of average
        return result;// return average
    }
}
```

Comment: please ,post error (stack-trace out put) .

Comment: Thank you.please ,can you post  input file ? do you post input file example ,i can run and check error.

Comment: `String pline` is empty in the `extractName()` method. Do you have empty lines in the input file? Or a newline at the end?

Comment: the input file is made up of name and then 4 scores in one line and then it goes to the next line with the same format. it might not show up here but it should be like this name 75 86 95 84

Comment: @Cinnam , I also guess it. I think , the error is passed has , input file some error.

Comment: @WatsDavies You code is woriking fine.I checked , and give expected out out.

Comment: i think the mistake is in the input file, sorry for taking your time i will try to change it . Thank you

Comment: You could check if the line is empty and ignore it if it is.

Comment: there has to be no absolutely no spaces other than the spaces between the numbers and names otherwise it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the input file it has to have very few spaces otherwise it doesnt work